# iPad orienatation need :application rejected

Tags: ipad, orientation, ios-simulator

I want to know that does apple approves application having any two of the orientation?

Like Landscape Left and Landscape right , 
Or Portrait mode and Portrait mode Upside down,

My application is having functionality of Drawing and to shows number of images .

Is it only required or I need to use all orientation for the application.

I had put only one orientation and application was rejected but I came to know from some sources that apple allows any two of the orientation , Is it true?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the thread in the comments below I think you need to support at least 2 rotations. So Both portraits or both landscape or all 4 rotations.

(in my opinion, if your app is landscape you must support both rotations, if it's portrait Apple may be more accepting if you don't support portrait upside down)

Comment: Can you please let me know the source if you do have, so that I can prove my self to my colleagues.

Comment: No source, sorry, but this thread might help? http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/5697

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply. I also came to know from my sources by making sore researches , Apple allows any of the two orientation , let me try my app again with both Landscape orientation. Hope for best...

Comment: fingers crossed. please can you post back here what the outcome is, I'm developing a landscape only app as well so I hope you get through.

Comment: My application is Accepted by apple, here is the link to my application http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kids-elc/id405476898?mt=8&ls=1.

Answer (score 0):

Apple require that for iPad you must support all orientations. That's just fact, and there is no possibility to do anything with that.